# Django ManyToMany relationship having through parameter

Tags: django, api, django-models, tastypie

I have the following models for one of my Django apps:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Seller(models.Model):
    seller_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    order_details = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through="OrderDetails")

class OrderDetails(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
```

I am using tasty pie for my api's. When I am trying to make a get request on the order's received, I need order_details object nested within the order.

Since the **order_details** field in **Order** model is a many-to-many field referring to the **Products** table but storing the data in **OrderDetails** table, it is giving me error mentioning that the *Product object has no Seller item* (Which is true).

How can I achieve the desired result through my API?

Comment: My problem was with Order tasty-pie API. I had a trouble with dehydrate on Order Model.

Comment: I have 3 different foreign keys in my OrderDetails table.